# How to call a partial view within a Modal using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, partial-views

I have a list of products and you want to display a modal window to edit the parameters of these products

for this you have in each row a button that calls the modal ....

[image: Index]

my Edit button in Index.cshtml:

```
 <td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning" onclick="EditarProducto(@item.Kn_CodigoProducto)">Editar </a>

 </td>
```

my script in Index.cshtml:

```
<script>
    var EditarProducto = function (codigoProducto) {

        var url = "/Productoes/EditarProducto?Kn_CodigoProducto="+codigoProducto;

        $("#EditModalBody").load(url, function () {
            $("#myModalEditar").modal("show");
        })
    }
    </script>
```

my modal Bootstrap in Index view:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalEditar">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Editar Producto</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="EditModalBody">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my ActionResult in controller:

```
 public ActionResult EditarProducto (int Kn_CodigoProducto)
        {
            Producto model = new Producto();

            if(Kn_CodigoProducto >= 0)
            {
                var producto = db.Productoes.Where(c => c.Kn_CodigoProducto == Kn_CodigoProducto).FirstOrDefault();

                model.v_Nombre = producto.v_Nombre;              
            }

            return PartialView("_PartialEditar", model);
        }
```

and my partial view that receives the model sent from the controller:

```
@model Dominio.Producto

<div class="jumbotron">
    <label>Esto es una prueba @Model.v_Nombre</label>
</div>
```

I have the partial view inside the folder along with the Index.cshtml view

[image: Partial]

Also I have referenced the corresponding scripts, what is happening? What is missing? It is the first time that I work with partial and modal views ... am I doing it correctly?

Expected behavior: when you click on the edit button, the modal opens

Behavior obtained: although when clicking on the edit button it enters the action of my controller, it does not show the modal

any help for me?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: I'm not getting any error in my console ... Suggestion? @StephenMuecke

Comment: In addition, are you editing properties other that those shown in your table? If not, then there is no need to make ajax calls for this - you can just populate the modal inputs with the values from the corresponding table row

Comment: he has achieved this error in my list of VS errors ... " 
,"ai.operation.name":"GET Productoes/EditarProducto"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"lBN/hrIogHE=","name":"GET Productoes/EditarProducto","duration":"00:00:05.0070000","success":true,"responseCode":"200","url":"http://localhost:59100/Productoes/EditarProducto?Kn_CodigoProducto=19","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<script>
    var EditarProducto = function (codigoProducto) {

        var url = "/Productoes/EditarProducto?Kn_CodigoProducto="+codigoProducto;

        $("#EditModalBody").load(url, function () {
            $("#myModalEditar").modal("show");
        })
    }
    </script>
```

Can you try this:

```
    <script>
      var EditarProducto = function (codigoProducto) {

      var url = "/Productoes/EditarProducto?Kn_CodigoProducto="+codigoProducto;

    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',            
            success: function (result) {                
                $('#EditModalBody').html(result);  
                $("#myModalEditar").modal("show");                                                 
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write jquery to invoke modal popup, instead you can use data-toggle and data-target attribuites.

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEditar">Editar </a>
```

Comment: in this way I would not be passing the parameters to my modal window

Comment: Use a function to pass the paramateters on click.